# Syntax error in Update asp.net Need someone to find the problem with my sentence

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, oledb, oledbconnection

Hello guys i have problem with my sentence...
I have an EditInfo Page and i want to make that the info u put in textbox will change ur info that u register...
And i have a problem with my sentence
Can anyone find the problem for me please?

```
    public static bool EditUser(string userName, string passWord, string firstName, string lastName, string eMail, string cityID)
{
    string connectionStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\DataBase.mdb";
    OleDbConnection connectObj = new OleDbConnection(connectionStr);
    string mySql = "UPDATE Users SET UserPass='" + passWord + "',";
    mySql += "FirstName='" + firstName + "',";
    mySql += "LastName='" + lastName + "',";
    mySql += "Email='" + eMail + "',";
    mySql += "Place='" + cityID + "',";
    mySql += "WHERE UserName='" + userName + "'";
    OleDbCommand myCommandObj = new OleDbCommand(mySql, connectObj);
    connectObj.Open();
    myCommandObj.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connectObj.Close();
    return true;
}
```

[Picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9rRv.png)

Comment: Do NOT use string concatenation to create sql queries. It is susceptible for sql injection attacks. Use parameterized queries instead.

Comment: The "'," after cityID should not contain a comma but a space toseparate from the WHERE clause. BUT: NEVER construct SQL commands from user input. Use Parameters instaead

Comment: What do you mean Parameters bro

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements

Comment: Can you maybe help me bro? I am working on EditInfo page, For example if i register to my site and want to change data i can go to editinfo page and change it but its not working for me... :( I wrote a question about it and no one helped me yet...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53350765/database-doing-problem-with-my-rows-and-with-my-editinfo-html-page

Answer (score 0):

Missing space?

```
...
mySql += "Place='" + cityID + "'<<space here no comma>>";
mySql += "WHERE UserName='" + userName + "'";
```